# Creating page API (through Graph) does not work

Tags: onenote

I'm trying to create pages using the beta API for OneNote (through Graph).  Even though I've completely emptied out my OneNote (no notebooks), I still get 20117 - An item with this name already exists in this location.  I've tested and I can create a Notebook just fine through this, but pages just refuse to be created (oddly enough, a default Notebook and Section will be created, but the page won't)

The URL I'm sending the POST to is: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/notes/pages?sectionName=Quick%20Notes

The HTML content for the page I'm providing is:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing Page</title>
    <meta name="created" content="2015-07-22T09:00:00-08:00" />
  </head>
  <body>
    yeaaaah
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For one of the calls that failed with this error, can you provide us with the value of the X-CorrelationId header so we can debug further?

Also, can you try with a different section name?